# CS50 Pset1 Cash error "expected identifier or '('" meaning?

Tags: c, cs50

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    {
        float dollars;
        // prompt user for "0.00" value
        do
        {
            dollars = get_float("Change owed: ");
        }
        while(dollars <= 0);
    }
    // print amount of coins used for change
        printf("%f\n", get_change(dollars));

    int get_change(float dollars);

    {
        //calculate which coins will be used
        int cents = round(dollars * 100);
        int coins = 0;
        int denom[] = {25, 10, 5, 1};

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++);
        {
            coins += cents / denom[i];
            cents = cents % denom[i];
        }
        return coins;
    }
}
```

Doing Pset1 in CS50 and I'm completely lost as to why my code isn't working. Getting syntax error

> cash.c:6:1: error: expected identifier or '('

Comment: It looks like you put one function inside another function.

Comment: Note that `dollars` is only in scope between the `{` and `}` around the `do { … } while (…);` loop; it is not available to the `printf()` statement.  You declare `get_change()` in the middle of `main()`, after you've called it; this is not correct.  Note that to be a nested function (a GCC extension), you'd omit the semicolon at the end of that line.   Then you have another block of code – which tries to access the inaccessible `dollars;` variable, amongst other problems.  The general idea of the loop and array is good though — we don't often see that in answers to this CS50 question.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you put one function inside another function. I don't have access to the header file, but I think what you need is more like the following.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void) {

    float dollars;
    // prompt user for "0.00" value
    do {
        dollars = get_float("Change owed: ");
    } while (dollars <= 0);

    // print amount of coins used for change
    printf("%f\n",get_change(dollars));
    return 0;
}

int get_change(float dollars) {
    //calculate which coins will be used
    int cents = round(dollars * 100);
    int coins = 0;
    int denom[] = {25, 10, 5, 1};

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++);
    {
        coins += cents / denom[i];
        cents = cents % denom[i];
    }
    return coins;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remove `;` in this line:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++);
```

and here:

```
int get_change(float dollars);
```

move `get_change` to first of file or use function declarations.