# CS50 Pset1 Cash: "undefined reference to 'get_change'"

Tags: c, cs50

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    // prompt user for "0.00" value
    float dollars;
    double get_change(float dollars);
        // prompt user for "0.00" value
    do
        {
            dollars = get_float("Change owed: ");
        }
    while(dollars <= 0);
    printf("%f\n", get_change(dollars));

        //calculate which coins will be used
    int cents = round(dollars * 100);
    int coins = 0;
    int denom[] = {25, 10, 5, 1};

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            coins += cents / denom[i];
            cents = cents % denom[i];
        }
    return coins;
}
```

Doing Pset1 Cash in CS50. Getting error message "In function `main':
/home/ubuntu/workspace/pset1/cash/cash2.c:15: undefined reference to`get_change'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make:  [cash2] Error 1" very confused

Comment: you are missing the function declaration **double get_change(float dollars);** and the function?

Comment: what is the function declaration? i'm confused

Comment: You seem to be attempting to define `get_change` inside `main`. I suggest you review the relevant material about functions again.

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_functions.htm . read this

Comment: You declared and called the function `get_change()`, but you never defined it.  (Declaration after `float dollars;` — call in `printf()` statement.)  The code preceded by the comment `calculate which coins will be used` is probably intended to be the body of the function.  You only seem to be counting the total number of coins and not identifying which coins.  The vending machine at my office distributes $1 coins too.  (But you weren't expected to deal with $1 coins, though your code makes it fairly easy to do so — good job using a loop and an array.)

Comment: See also [CS50 Pset1 Cash — error expected identifier or '(' meaning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54165283/cs50-pset1-cash-error-expected-identifier-or-meaning), but this is a different question (just about).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - It's a question by the same person

Comment: @StoryTeller: Yes, and with quite a lot of code in common, though the details are different this time.

Comment: regarding: `int cents = round(dollars * 100);`  The syntax for `round()` is: `double round(double x);`  However, the posted code is passing a `float` rather than a `double` to the function And the returned value is being assigned to a 'int' rather than a `double`.   the C language will use the `implicit conversion`  feature to try and fix the problems.  However, much better if the code actually tried to do the work.  for instance by: 1) `float dollars;` changed to `double dollars` and `int cents = round(dollars * 100);` changed to: `int cents = (int)floor( round( dollars * 100.0 ) );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following proposed code:

1. performs the operation of the total number of coins needed (assuming that there is no paper money)
2. properly separates the functions
3. properly uses a prototype for the sub function
4. properly converts from `float` to `int`
5. properly defines constants as `float` by including a decimal point and a trailing 'f'

and now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <math.h>

int get_change( float dollars );


int main(void)
{
    // prompt user for "0.00" value
    float dollars;

    do
    {
        dollars = get_float("Change owed: ");
    }
    while(dollars <= 0.0f);

    printf("%d\n", get_change(dollars));
}

// returns number coins needed, not their denominations 
int get_change( float dollars )
{
    //calculate which coins will be used
    int cents = (int)floorf(dollars * 100.0f);
    int coins = 0;
    int denom[] = {25, 10, 5, 1};

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        coins += cents / denom[i];
        cents = cents % denom[i];
    }
    return coins;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <math.h>

int get_change(float dollars);

int main(void)
{
    float dollars;
    //prompts user for 0.00 amount
    do
    {
        dollars = get_float("change owed: ");
    }
    while (dollars < 0);
    //
    printf("%i\n", get_change(dollars));
}
int get_change(float dollars)
{
    //calculate how mnay coins will be used
    int cents = round(dollars * 100);
    int coins = 0;
    int denom[] = {25, 10, 5, 1};

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        coins += cents / denom[i];
        cents = cents % denom[i];
    }
    return coins;
}
```

MY OFFICIAL ANSWER TO MY QUESTION.